# Access ABP Application Service from Xamarin Forms

Tags: abp

On Abp community site there are a few articles on how to access an Abp endpoint from Xamarin/Maui. Basically it boils down to:

- create mobile client
- login with user name and password
- obtain access token
- use this token as bearer for API calls.

However, in the microservices samples there is a [Console](https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/blob/master/MicroserviceDemo/applications/ConsoleClientDemo/ClientDemoService.cs) app sample which has services injected and used. Now that would be quite awesome to use inside xamarin.

My question is: can abp application services be used directly in xamarin forms? I see no way of injecting the services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can share a couple of articles about it, I think those might help:

- https://community.abp.io/posts/consume-abp-api-from-xamarin-app-3by6fdz6

MAUI, but they'll work on Xamarin too:

- https://community.abp.io/posts/integrating-maui-client-via-using-openid-connect-aqjjwsdf
- https://community.abp.io/posts/abp-framework-consumed-by-a-.net-maui-app-e74fmblw

Comment: Thank you. While implementing something similar to examples above works, it would have been really cool to be able to inject app services directly.

Comment: Actually, this sees possible: https://community.abp.io/posts/using-abp-client-proxies-in-maui-with-openid-connect-em7x1s8k

Comment: Oh, I just saw you did that article. Don't tell me that I inspired you to write it :) Great work!